# How to check if an object is logically in an array, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to check if an object is logically in an array, when two object are logically equals(Just like the `equals` in Java), it will be treated as "in" the array

While I use `$.inArray` of `jQuery` to test below code, it retuans -1,indicating that the copied one is not treated as "in" the array.

```
var a =[{value: "G27", title: "G27"}];
$.inArray({value: "G27", title: "G27"},a); //returns -1
```

Above is just an example ,Is there an easy way for **generic** cases to achieve that

Comment: In javascript no two obects are ever the same, so it's going to be generally difficult, and you should probably try to figure out a better way of structuring your data.

Comment: You are creating two objects, but when you do it like this, it will work:

`var b = {value: "G27", title: "G27"};
var a =[b];
$.inArray(b,a); //returns 0`

Comment: I think you might find a possible answer here : [array.contains(obj) in JavaScript][1] !


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to check for each key-value pair in a for loop:

```
function exist(arr, obj){
  var len = Object.keys(obj).length;
  var count = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      count=0;
      for(var key in obj){
          if(obj[key] == arr[i][key]){
            count++;
          }
      }
      if(count == len && count == Object.keys(arr[i]).length){
        console.log("Exists!!");
        return;
      }
  }
  console.log("Don't exist!!");
}

var arr =[{value: "G27", title: "G27"}];
var b = {value: "G27", title: "G27"};
//Call
exist(arr, b);
```

Comment: This is a non dynamic solution, because it assumes a simple object with only Key/value attributes. So, each time a new property is added to the object, he has to edit this loop

Answer (score 1):

If you feel like using underscore.js, you could try using [`_.findWhere()`](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere):

```js
var a = [{value: "G27", title: "G27"}];
snippet.log(_.findWhere(a, {value: "G27", title: "G27"}) !== undefined); // returns true
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Scimonster, no problem to reject my edit .. as I see you made the answer even better, I just liked your answer and tried to proof how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the filter method of the array.

```
var arr = [{value: "G27", title: "G27"}];
// Don't call filter on arr because this will mutate arr itself. Instead of creating a new array.
var filteredArr = Array.prototype.filter.call(arr, function(item) {
    return item.value == "G27" && iem.title == "G27";
});

if(filteredArr.length > 0) {
    // Item exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try custom search:

```js
var indexOf = function(array, obj) {
  var i = array.length;
  var o;
  while (o = array[--i]) //note, its assignment
    if (obj.value === o.value && obj.title === o.title)
      break;
  return i;
};

var arr = [{
  value: "G27",
  title: "G27"
}, {
  value: "G28",
  title: "G28"
}, {
  value: "G29",
  title: "G29"
}];

console.log(indexOf(arr, {
  title: "G28",
  value: "G28"
})); //<-- 1

console.log(indexOf(arr, {
  title: "G30",
  value: "G30"
})); //<-- -1
```

Comment: Problem is for object defined e.g as: `{
  title: "G28",
  value: "G28"
}` Or `{
  title: "G28",
  value: "G28"
}` is the same than `{
  value: "G28",
  title: "G28"
}`